# How to view saved page source in Appium app

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

While running automated test using appium I used `driver.getPageSource()` and stored it as a XML file. I also took the screenshot of the same page using `driver.takeScreenshot()` and saved it as a PNG file. Now how do I view it in Appium app so that it correspondingly maps to the elements with the xml data.

Is there a open option in Appium like in uiautomatorviewer?
I couldn't use uiautomator because it requires uix file. But I couldn't find open option in appium.

Answer (score 1):

UIAutomatorviewer is simple tool to start with mobile automation , however it has some limitations

**Less robust:**

Throws random errors while working with native apps

**Limited functionality:**

Limited features as compared to **APPIUM Desktop**

These limitations do not allow UIAUTOMATORVIEWER to be a universal choice among the automation engineers , and mostly it’s used along with **Appium Desktop**.

For **Installation and Usage** you can refer below URL

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Due to the complex setup of Appium, it is quite difficult to be dependant only on Appium for mobile automation.
With Appium Studio of SeeTest you can easily identify objects.

Appium Studio mitigates all of Appium's challenges with ease. There is also an object spy for easier object and XPath identification. Tests are recorded simply. Actions carried out on the device reflection are recorded in an easily exported and executable test written in the language of your choice.

Visit [this](https://experitest.com/blog-cat/when-appium-for-ios-is-not-getting-it-done-enter-appium-studio/) blog for more details.

Refer their docs to get started https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TD/Appium+Studio